# Easiest way to post videos directly to S3?

Tags: 7, files

I am working on a video sharing site and I plan to use the [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video) module. Amazon S3 is also being used as the file system. The problem is how to override/extend it so the video file skips the intermediate step of uploading to the server and directly [upload to S3 using a separate POST request](http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Drupal 7, take a look at these two projects:

- [Storage API](http://drupal.org/project/storage_api)
- [Amazon S3](http://drupal.org/project/AmazonS3)

Both of these let you store file uploads on S3 instead of the local filesystem.

Comment: I plan to use the Amazon S3 module for image uploads but I would prefer if video files didn't need to be uploaded to the server first and then uploaded again to Amazon S3. Just a major bandwidth hog to have the server accepting uploads.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know the S3 module had CDN support. Thanks for the suggestion.